# To loop the record till the to_reference id is not equal to 0 and also apply and or condition

Tags: php, mysql, regex, database, loops

I am stuck to the following problem.I am applying page logic to the website which is survey kind of data. I am unable to fetch the records in loop till the from_reference_id tends to null, And also there can be and/or condition between the two reference from_reference_id and to_reference_id and loop ends till to_reference_id tends to null.Also there can be and/or condition between the reference id which is being matched with the answer provided on the survey. The aggregate result will defined the page redirection. As for example from_reference_id is 1 and to to_reference is 2 then based on the question it will be solved as equation like this. So I just want to route page to be redirected.

```
if(q1:a1) is selected then goto page 3
or (q2:a1) is selected then goto page 3
```

where `q1` represent question and `a1` denotes answer1
Here is the database structure 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CWHT.png

the code I have tried

```
$sql_select_query="SELECT * from `tbl_branching_logic` where `p_id`='$page_id' and `s_id`='$global_survey_id' and `r_id`='$r_id'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql_select_query);    
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      if($row['to_reference_id']!=0 && $row['and_or']!='')
      {
          //condition

      }
    }
```

This is the html structure image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr0Ly.png)

Comment: why you don't use `WHERE to_reference_id > 0` ?

Comment: I need the results till 0(to_reference_id) , 0 means there is no referencing of and/or condition with any other reference id

Comment: stop using mysql_ commands! Please use PDO, or at the very least, mysqli

Comment: @testqa yes, but you could exclude all rows with to_reference_id < 1

Comment: Please see the html structure also https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr0Ly.png commented at last , My server version is 5.5.3 so there is no problem in mysql, If i using php7 then I need to resolve it

Comment: @testqa again you don't understand see id (39,40,41) in it there is from_reference_id is 1 which is reference to 2 and there is or condition applied it in then in id 40 the from reference id is referenced to 3 with and condition now in the id 41 there is no and/or condition hence there is no reference id so it will tends to 0 see database structure carefully