# Apply logical operator between array elements in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, logical-operators

I have a three `array`, one is the boolean array which contains all boolean values, second is the conditional array which contains and/or operations between the array of boolean and the third one is the route page array which if the expression is true then it is redirect to next route page else not
eg array

```
array(2) { [0]=> bool(true) [1]=> bool(false) ...} // boolean array
array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "or" [1]=> string(0) "" ...} // conditional operator array
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "2" ... } // route page
```

the expression would be made `(bool(true) or bool(false))` hence the result would be `bool(true)` final and hence it would redirect to page two i.e What I need the recursive expression in loop

Here is the code what I applied

```
 for($i=0;$i<count($boolean);$i++)
           {
               if($and_or[$i]=='and')
               {
                   $operator='&&';
               }
               else
               {
                   $operator='||';
               }
               $result=($boolean[$i].$operator.$boolean[$i+1]);

           }
           var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Is there is blank value second element of conditional operator array?

Comment: Some questions: What does recursion have to do with this? Is the third array relevant for the question? Some remarks: What you are doing is appending strings, not applying logical operators. With your code you are also going beyond the end of the array with `$boolean[$i+1]`.

Comment: yes the blank value denotes the end of conditional operator and no more ahead operation will be done

Comment: @Gerriet so how to resolve and make the expression, the third array is the final result which if the expression seems to be true then redirection of page will be there and I am applying this condition in page logic of the survey. For more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434757/to-loop-the-record-till-the-to-reference-id-is-not-equal-to-0-and-also-apply-and?noredirect=1#comment75866825_44434757

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this brings you closer to your goal:

```
 for($i=0;$i<count($boolean)-1;$i++)
 {
   if ($i < count($and_or) && !empty($and_or[$i]) {
     if($and_or[$i]=='and')
     {
           $operator='&&';
           $result = $boolean[$i] && $boolean[$i+1];
     }
     else
     {
          $operator='||';
          $result = $boolean[$i] || $boolean[$i+1];
     }
     $operation=($boolean[$i].$operator.$boolean[$i+1]);
 }
 var_dump($operation);
 var_dump($result);
```

Please note that you use most boolean values two times (the second value is the second operator for the first operation and the first operator for the second operation).

Comment: what if more than two boolean condition are there in the array will it be applicable, suppose there are three values in the boolean will it be applicable if there is `or` operation between (1 and 2  ) and then this result will be for three (3) and and condtion

Answer (score 5):

As I didn't like the complexity of the suggested answers I dug deeper and ended up scanning the array functions listed in http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php.

These might not be the best performance-wise, but are simple and I wouldn't consider the performance penalty if you're not applying on a large array.

For logical **AND** (**&&**) use this:

```
var_export(!in_array(false,array(true,true,false,false,true,false))); //false
```

or this:

```
var_export((bool)array_product(array(true,true,false,false,true,false))); //false
```

For logical **OR** (**||**) use this:

```
var_export(in_array(true,array(true,true,false,false,true,false))); //true
```

or this:

```
var_export(array_search(true,array(true,true,false,false,true,false))!==false); //true
```

I am taking a wild guess the **in_array**'s would be faster. But with PHP 7 out who knows...

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $boolean ); $i++ ) {
    switch( $and_or[ $i ] ) {
        case '&&':
        case 'and':
            $result = $boolean[ $i ] && $boolean[ $i + 1 ];
            break;
        case '||':
        case 'or':
            $result = $boolean[ $i ] || $boolean[ $i + 1 ];
            break;
    }
    var_dump( $result );
}
```

You can also use `and`, `or` operators.
If you have more than two operators, you can use `eval` function like this:

```
$boolean = [1,0,0];
$o = ['&&','or'];
echo $r = "return ($boolean[0] $o[0] $boolean[1]) $o[1] $boolean[2];";
var_dump( eval($r) );
```

Comment: what if more than two boolean condition are there in the array will it be applicable, suppose there are three values in the boolean will it be applicable if there is or operation between (1 and 2 ) and then this result will be for three (3) and and condtion –

Comment: but the and or condition are dynamic it is user defined array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "or" [1]=> string(0) "" ...} , The user will defined

Comment: @testqa you can get a logical string from user and pass to `eval` function to execute this. care about security issues.

Comment: my question is how would i differentiate if there is two boolean or three then accordingly  echo $r = "return ($boolean[0] $o[0] $boolean[1]) $o[1] $boolean[2];"; I mean to say it should work dynamically

Comment: you have suggested a good idea about eval, thanks could you please more elaborate how to make it dynamically the logical expression, This is only my main question means this expression echo $r = "return ($boolean[0] $o[0] $boolean[1]) $o[1] $boolean[2];"; should be made dynamically

Comment: @testqa You mean such a thing? https://pastebin.com/1r9p65ws. please make an example of your user defined inputs that you need to solve it.

Comment: no the array would be like above only, only the size and count may be different, I means to say if array(3) { [0]=> bool(true) [1]=> bool(false) [2]=>true } // boolean array
array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "or" [1]=> string(0) "and"  [2]=>'' } then expression would be of three variable and so like this now the expression would be ((true or false  ) and true) and or condition is selected by user and will be put up in the above array

Comment: thanks @MahdiY  it workes for changing the value of boolean and also the array size of boolean as well as or operator